# How to subtract two date and time fieds in excel

Tags: excel

I have two fields having date and time like: 11/08/2018 12:04 and 11/8/2018 12:00. I want Excel to subtract these fields and return me a new field with the difference(which in this case is 4mins)

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what problem / error did you experience?

Answer (score 0):

TEXT function can used to calculate time.

Assuming the date values are in A1 and A2

=TEXT(A1-A2,"h:mm:ss")